# Yii - element render + errors

Tags: forms, yii, element, render

I have tried the below to display the form fields without the form start and end tag, but it seems that it doesn't display the errors.

```
public function render()
{
    $output = '';

    foreach($this->getElements() as $element)
        $output .= $element->render();

    return $output;
}
```

Any ideas why doesn't it display the errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the implementation of `CFormModel::render` [here](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/form/CForm.php#375); there are a few interconnected methods that `render` taps into immediately following.

To specifically answer your question, in line 459 of the above we see

```
$output.=$this->getActiveFormWidget()->errorSummary($model)."\n";
```

That's how Yii injects the error summary. And [here](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/form/CFormInputElement.php#165) you can see how a `CFormInputElement` renders itself; again, there is an explicit call to code that renders the error in the method `renderError` which is below.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to call `submitted()` and `validate()` lol. Anyway, to display the errors after each field I had to write `'showErrorSummary' => true` in the form view.